# encoding in REST request between 2 tomcats

Tags: java, rest, grails

I have 2 tomcat 7.0.26 servers and send REST requests from the first (grails application with rest plugin) to the second (rest service realization).

I have an encoding problem at the second tomcat with non-English letters (they are not displayed correctly).

How do I set UTF-8 encoding to REST request?
how to filter encoding at REST service?
can you give any advice?

Comment: Since REST is HTTP based, I think you should be able to set the encoding in HTTP header, probably Content-type field.

Comment: i tried it: set content-type to rest request (didn't work)

Comment: Check out this post, may be it'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file

Answer (score 0):

in your method where you do the rest based call you can do

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") that should do it.
```

Comment: i have only parameters (as JSON string) at service method, no request

Comment: How are you sending the request from one server to the other ? Or receiving it  ? You need to have a controller somewhere to send it and receive it

Comment: you are right: i have service that sending resquest and mapped controller for receiving
example: delegate.post(query : query, body : body, requestContentType : JSON,  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8")

Comment: Can you dump the data before you pass it to the service and see how it looks ?

Comment: i look at my data from debug mode and it's valid

Comment: Could you post the code where you are getting the data and then passing it on to the service and also the service code ?

Comment: sending rest request:
<code>
withRest(uri: encodeUriUTF8(url),   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8") {
            delegate.handler.success = { response, reader ->
                restResponse.responseCode = response.status
                restResponse.json = modifyJSON(reader)
            }
            delegate.handler.failure = { response, data ->
                handleRestFailure(response, data, restResponse)
            }
            delegate.put(query : query, body : body, requestContentType : JSON, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        }
</code>

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept all the request objects in filter and set UTF-8 encoding